# Why does the order of css selectors matter?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is example 1 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bessarabov/s581mv5a/)):

html:

```
<div class="class_1 class_2">
This is a text
</div>
```

css:

```
.class_1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: blue;
 }

.class_2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

It works exaclty the way I expect. I have `<div class="class_1 class_2">` and
the result is `color` from `class_1` and `font-size` from `class_2`. As I
understand it the `font-size` rule in `class_2` replaces the `font-size` rule
from the `class_1`.

Here is the example 2 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bessarabov/qesL1sj9/)).

It has the same html:

```
<div class="class_1 class_2">
This is a text
</div>
```

But the css selectors are in reversed order:

```
.class_2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.class_1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: blue;
}
```

And this code does not work as I expect. I exect it to work exacly as the
example 1. But only the rules from `class_1` are applied. I've written
`<div class="class_1 class_2">` and I expect that the rules from `class_1`
will be applied and then they will be changed by `class_2`.

Why does this happen? What is the rule that makes css work this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For selectors having equal specificity, the rules are applied in the order in which they appear in the *CSS file* (or files, if there are multiple).  The order of the CSS classes given in the HTML `class` attribute is irrelevant.

This means that in the second example, the rules for `.class_2` are applied first, followed by the rules for `.class_1`.  As a result, when any attribute is defined in both blocks, the rules in the second block supersede those in the first when both classes are present on an element.

So, the rules from both blocks *were* applied!  (Add a `color` attribute to the `.class_2` block to prove this to yourself.)  But, after the `.class_2` block was applied, the `.class_1` block was -- and it also defines a `font-size` attribute, superseding the same attribute defined in `.class_2`.